# Rich HTML tray menu in a desktop web application

Tags: desktop-application, electron, nw.js, phonegap-desktop-app

I want to create a tray menu app with custom buttons, sliders, maybe some nice transition effect, a header and footer like this:

[image: menu]

The application needs to work on Linux, Windows and Mac. 
I guessed it should be possible with a desktop web app + some HTML, but I can't find any useful example for any framework. Every example uses the OS' menu that just doesn't have the elements I need.

**Can anyone direct me how to more or less implement this in any of the web app frameworks?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be done in electron quite easily, I've actually created a few tray apps myself in the below images:

[image: Tray app] [image: Trap app 2]

The rudimentary files you need are:

- `index.html`
- `main.js`
- `package.json`

In the `index.html` you would design your app the way you wanted it to look. In my example above I just used a couple of input boxes and styled them with CSS.

The `main.js` file is where you would put your main code to power the app.

In the `package.json` file is where you put the details about your app, dev dependencies etc.

The main file you should be concerned with is the `main.js` file. Below is an example of the `main.js` file for the app above. I've added comments to help you understand:

```js
// Sets variables (const)
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Tray} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

const assetsDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'img')

let tray = undefined
let window = undefined

// Don't show the app in the doc
app.dock.hide()

// Creates tray & window
app.on('ready', () => {
  createTray()
  createWindow()
})

// Quit the app when the window is closed
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit()
})

// Creates tray image & toggles window on click
const createTray = () => {
  tray = new Tray(path.join(assetsDirectory, 'icon.png'))
  tray.on('click', function (event) {
    toggleWindow()
  })
}

  const getWindowPosition = () => {
  const windowBounds = window.getBounds()
  const trayBounds = tray.getBounds()

  // Center window horizontally below the tray icon
  const x = Math.round(trayBounds.x + (trayBounds.width / 2) - (windowBounds.width / 2))

  // Position window 4 pixels vertically below the tray icon
  const y = Math.round(trayBounds.y + trayBounds.height + 3)

  return {x: x, y: y}
}

// Creates window & specifies its values
const createWindow = () => {
  window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 250,
        height: 310,
        show: false,
        frame: false,
        fullscreenable: false,
        resizable: false,
        transparent: true,
        'node-integration': false
    })
    // This is where the index.html file is loaded into the window
    window.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

  // Hide the window when it loses focus
  window.on('blur', () => {
    if (!window.webContents.isDevToolsOpened()) {
      window.hide()
    }
  })
}

const toggleWindow = () => {
  if (window.isVisible()) {
    window.hide()
  } else {
    showWindow()
  }
}

const showWindow = () => {
  const position = getWindowPosition()
  window.setPosition(position.x, position.y, false)
  window.show()
  window.focus()
}

ipcMain.on('show-window', () => {
  showWindow()
})
```

Below is an example of the `package.json` file:

```js
{
  "name": "NAMEOFAPP",
  "description": "DESCRIPTION OF APP",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "NAME OF AUTHOR",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-packager": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

So, If you create a simple `index.html` file saying "Hello World", place the above codes into the `main.js` file and `package.json` file respectively and run the app it will run from the tray.

If you have no idea how to use Electron, you need to figure that out first ([Electron docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/)). It will then become clear where to place which file and how to run the app.

Comment: Thanks! So this code is showing a borderless window next to the tray icon. That's neat!

Comment: If you want content (like headers/text etc) to be inside the window, you need to edit the `index.html` file, just like you would with a website

Comment: Would this work with different panel positions? (left, right, top, bottom)

Comment: Oh, I thought you can move it around.:)

Comment: You can move the window around, but not the actual tray icon. In the `main.js` code above where it says: `// Center window horizontally below the tray icon` you can edit it so that is moves horizontally either left or right. Same goes for the line below it, to move it vertically

Comment: `getBounds()` doesn't work on Linux. Any idea how I get tray's coordinates?

Comment: I'm not too sure as I don't use Linux, although this seems to be a non fixed issue - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=309969

Comment: Why not just `window.loadFile('index.html')` ?                                                                         Instead of  `window.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');`